# Taking path to file from variable in C, C++

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I'm doing a little project using C, C++ and `dirent.h`. I want to ask if its possible to take a path to a folder/file from a variable:

```cpp
string fileName;
cout << "Create new file" << endl;
cin>>fileName;

CreateDirectory(documentLocation.c_str()+fileName.c_str(), NULL);
```

`documentLocation` is my variable I gave at the beginning of the program where I want to create a new directory. Adding `fileName`, I want to create a new directory in this folder. But I get an error:

> expression must have integral or enum type

Comment: Of course it is. Functions don't care where their parameters come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `+` to concatenate C strings. Concatenate the `std::string`s first, then get the C string from that.

```
CreateDirectory((documentLocation + fileName).c_str(), NULL);
```

Comment: thank you, its working, and how about starting a new exe with system("start calc.exe") but instead of calc.exe i want to use path to .exe for file I want open?

Comment: You can use variables for anything. Nothing cares where the values come from.

Comment: @mathes you can do the exact same thing for `system()` that you do for `CreateDirectory()`, eg: `std::string exeName = "calc.exe"; system(("start " + exeName).c_str());` Though you really should be using `CreateProcess()` instead of `system()` for that

Comment: @mathes If the answer solve your issue you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it then it may help other people are searching on this.

Answer (score 1):

`c_str()` returns a `const char *`, so in

```
documentLocation.c_str()+fileName.c_str()
```

You try to add two `const char *`, which does not work.

`std::string` overloads the `+` operator:

```
std::string path = documentLocation + fileName;
CreateDirectory(path.c_str(), NULL);
```

First add (concatenate) the two strings, then take the `c_str()` of the result.